# ffmpeg not creating thumbnail images after deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to  write a program to create thumbnail image of video file using ffmpeg. It working fine on local machine but after deploy my project to server machine no thumbnail image is creating, the problem is with ffmpeg permission. I set full permission to everyone on server but no output

please help me out
have it give any extra permissions to server machine??

Comment: hi meer, could I maybe ask how you have done this? I'm trying to do the same, but my image isn't working (even on local)....